# SQL query to return most recent data per group, then active/inactive per different group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that returns the result I want, but it runs a long time.  Does anyone know a better way of writing this?

I need one row per group of Prgno/Prgdate.
First I need to determine the status of each employee by choosing the most recent record.
Then of those, if any employee is active, the whole group is active.

It's not enough to just choose the 'A' records because an Inactive record for a specific employee may be more current that the Active record.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT X_Prgno,X_Prgdate,X_Status 
FROM (
    -- sq2 choose the 1st record when ordering by status, this will choose Active before Inactive
    SELECT X_Prgno,X_Prgdate,X_Status,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY X_Prgno,X_Prgdate ORDER BY X_Status) AS rn
    FROM (
        -- sq1 choose the most recently updated record per empno, prgno, prgdate
        SELECT X_Empno,X_Prgno,X_Prgdate,X_Status,
               X_Upddate AS Updated_datetime,
               MAX(X_Upddate) OVER (PARTITION BY X_Empno,X_Prgno,X_Prgdate) AS Max_Updated_datetime
        FROM X_demo
        ) sq1
    WHERE Updated_datetime = Max_Updated_datetime) sq2
WHERE rn = 1
```

I first selected the most recent record grouped by 3 columns (prgno, prgdate, employee).  Then selected the Active record first, if an active records exists, grouped by only 2 columns (prgno, prgdate).

Sample: (I hope this helps, you can run the above query on this sample set)

```
create table X_demo(
X_Prgno char(6),
X_Prgdate char(8),
X_Empno int,
X_Status char(1),
X_Upddate datetime);
insert into X_demo values ('P43','20170124',1033,'A','2015-07-06 23:05:32.000');
insert into X_demo values ('P43','20170124',1033,'I','2015-07-06 23:05:07.000');
insert into X_demo values ('P43','20170124',1033,'I','2015-07-06 23:03:58.000');
insert into X_demo values ('P43','20170124',1034,'A','2015-06-03 09:29:46.000');
insert into X_demo values ('P43','20170124',1029,'I','2015-06-03 07:26:36.000');
insert into X_demo values ('P43','20170124',1033,'I','2015-06-02 14:52:53.000');
insert into X_demo values ('P43','20170124',1010,'I','2015-06-02 14:52:12.000');
insert into X_demo values ('P43','20170124',1029,'I','2015-08-29 13:27:35.000');
insert into X_demo values ('P43','20170124',1074,'I','2015-05-19 01:20:06.000');
```

If we group by Prgno, Prgdate, and Empno, we should return 6 rows, the most recent for each employee.
Then regroup by Prgno and Prgdate to return 'A' for this group.

Desired result:

```
X_Prgno X_Prgdate   X_Status
P43     20170124    A
```

Thanks for any help.

If I insert 2 additional records, more current records for the two Active employee records making them inactive, then the result for the group should be inactive.

```
insert into X_demo values ('P43','20170124',1033,'I','2017-01-27 09:30:00.000');
insert into X_demo values ('P43','20170124',1034,'I','2017-01-27 09:30:00.000');
```

Result:

```
X_Prgno X_Prgdate   X_Status
P43     20170124    I
```

Update - 2017-01-30

I changed the MAX OVER PARTITION part of the sub-query to use a ROW_NUMBER function.
It improved the query run time by a few seconds, but still runs too long.

```
SELECT X_Prgno,X_Prgdate,X_Status 
FROM (
    -- sq2 choose the 1st record when ordering by status, this will choose Active before Inactive
    SELECT X_Prgno,X_Prgdate,X_Status,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY X_Prgno,X_Prgdate ORDER BY X_Status) AS sq2_rn
    FROM (
        -- sq1 choose the most recently updated record per prgno, prgdate, empno
        SELECT X_Prgno,X_Prgdate,X_Empno,X_Status,X_upddate,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY X_Prgno,X_Prgdate,X_Empno
                        ORDER BY X_Upddate DESC,X_Status) AS sq1_rn
        FROM X_demo) sq1
    WHERE sq1_rn = 1) sq2
WHERE sq2_rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for any help.

Comment: so do you need only latest active records, if they exist, per group?

Comment: Post your desired result please.

Comment: Desired result is one row.  I included it above.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want one record for an employees on date date/prgno, where the active record is prioritized.

Understanding what you want to do can help simplify the query.

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (SELECT x.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY X_Prgno, X_PrgDate
                                ORDER BY X_Upddate DESC, status
                               ) as seqnum
      FROM X_demo x
     ) x
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

For this query, an index on `(X_Prgno, X_PrgDate, status, X_Upddate)` would help performance.

Comment: Almost, but not quite.  I need to find the most recent by employee, but then if ANY employee is Active, that makes the group Active.  The result I'm looking for is one row per Prgno/Prgdate.

Comment: I will see if I can add an index, its an application database, and we typically don't touch those.

Comment: @vkp and Gordon - Thanks, but still not the solution.  The above query returns one row, but not correct in all test cases.  The result for the group should be 'Inactive' if the **most recent** record for all employees is inactive.  The result should be 'Active' if the most recent record for any employee is active.  In the case that is wrong, employees 1033 and 1034 have a more recent record of inactive, no other employee is active, so the group should be inactive.

Comment: @NancyF . . . I think you just have to swap the `ORDER BY ` keys (as I just did).

Comment: I really think it needs to be a two-part query, because the inner query includes employee, and the outer query does not.  I can only interrogate the most recent record for each employee.  Then after I have the subset of most recent records, I can check if any of them are Active.  I can't sort by Status/Date because an Inactive record may be more current than an active record.  I can't sort by Date/Status because an Active record for a different employee may be more current that an inactive record.

Comment: My apologies if I just can't explain this better.  And thank you for your efforts.